# STR_TO_DATE() returns invalid date

Tags: mysql, sql

I was given a job to create a new table in the database with correct data type. Here are sample records:

```
RegisteredMonthYear
------------------------
May 2011
March 1998
January 2000
```

Before I will insert the converted value I tried to convert it using `STR_TO_DATE()` to check if the values are correct and the result were exactly not I want. This is my query:

```
SELECT  RegisteredMonthYear,
        STR_TO_DATE(RegisteredMonthYear, '%M %Y') NewDate,
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(RegisteredMonthYear, ' 01'), '%M %Y %d') newDate2,
        STR_TO_DATE(RegisteredMonthYear, '%M %Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY newDate3
FROM    TableName

+---------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+
| REGISTEREDMONTHYEAR |             NEWDATE             |            NEWDATE2            | NEWDATE3 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+
| May 2011            | April, 30 2011 00:00:00+0000    | May, 01 2011 00:00:00+0000     | (null)   |
| March 1998          | February, 28 1998 00:00:00+0000 | March, 01 1998 00:00:00+0000   | (null)   |
| January 2000        | December, 31 1999 00:00:00+0000 | January, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 | (null)   |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------+
```

see here for demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a67/7

As you can see, column `NEWDATE` is one day behind. Why are the result like this?

When I tried to concatenate `01` in the string in column `NEWDATE2` the result is as expected. Going back on `NEWDATE` column, I tried to add one day thinking that it will give exact value in column `NEWDATE3` but the result is `NULL`.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following formula ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/543c37/1)):

```
SELECT date(str_to_date(RegisteredMonthYear, '%M %Y'))
     + interval 1 day
FROM tablename
```

I have added extra `DATE()` call on top of `STR_TO_DATE()` - but it makes all the difference.

But in general I agree that this is one more really weird MySQL gotcha.

For example, in PostgreSQL, you don't need to add 1 day and you don't need extra casts, simple to_timestamp is enough:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('May 2011', 'Mon YYYY');

2013-05-01 00:00:00-07
```

Comment: as I browse the documentation, it says: `STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts...` why are you still passing the result of `STR_TO_DATE()` into `DATE()`? I guess this is a bug for `STR_TO_DATE()`.

Comment: That's why I said that this one more MySQL gotcha. Often you need to apply black magic to solve problems that should not exist in first place.

Comment: I guess this is also a bug.

Comment: updated answer to add example for Postgres and see how much more sane it is